# flutter: Failed with error code: failed-precondition

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: my firestore]

```
  @override
  Future<List<InvoiceModel>> fetchFailedTransactionLog() async {
    final snapshot = await db.collection(firestoreUsers)
    .doc(currentUser!.uid)
    .collection(firestoreTransacitonLog)
    .where('isSuccess', isEqualTo: false)
    .orderBy('created', descending: true)
    .get();
    final data = snapshot.docs.map((e) => InvoiceModel.fromFirestore(e)).toList();
    print('DATA =============> ${data}');
    return data;
  }
```

this is my database rules,
i only edited a little bit

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the invoice model,
i don't think there's something wrong with my model.
or should i change 'isSuccess' to string instead of boolean?

```
class InvoiceModel extends Equatable{
  final String id;
  final String invoiceNumber;
  final String paymentNumber;
  final String paymentMethod;
  final String name;
  final String? email;
  int? phoneNumber;
  final String? address;
  final DateTime created;
  final DateTime startDate;
  final DateTime expiryDate;
  final String? description;
  int nominal;
  int quantity;
  int total;
  bool? isSuccess;

  InvoiceModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.invoiceNumber,
    required this.paymentNumber,
    required this.paymentMethod,
    required this.name,
    this.email = "",
    this.phoneNumber,
    this.address = "",
    required this.created,
    required this.startDate,
    required this.expiryDate,
    this.description = "",
    required this.nominal,
    this.quantity = 1,
    required this.total,
    this.isSuccess
  });
}
```

i tried changing from 'isEqualTo: false' -> 'isNotEqualTo: true' but it still shows an error

Comment: share the error logs

Comment: it's only
flutter: Failed with error code: failed-precondition

Comment: just one line ?

Comment: also share database rules

Comment: can you share the `InvoiceModel` class too with editing the question ?

Comment: @Koya I have recreated your issue with what you have shared and I am able to get data perfectly, maybe I missed anything for that share your entire code.